# How to save all selected symptom IDs from a patient into an array and include that array when saving data to the database?

Tags: php

I am developing a medical consultation application using PHP and MySQL. Currently, I am facing an issue in saving all selected symptom IDs from a patient into the database. I am using a `foreach` loop to retrieve the selected symptoms from the form, and I am trying to save them into the `$arr_selected_symptom_ids` array.

```php
$arr_selected_symptom_ids = array(); // Initializing an array to store selected symptom IDs
$no = 0;

foreach ($_POST['gejala'] as $gejala) {
  $arr_id_gejala_terpilih[] = $gejala; // Simpan ID gejala yang dipilih
  $rgejala = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kode_gejala, nama_gejala FROM gejala WHERE id_gejala = " . $gejala));
  $list_data .= '
    <tr>
      <td>' . ++$no . '.    ' . '</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>' . '  ' . ' ' . $rgejala['kode_gejala'] . ' - ' . $rgejala['nama_gejala'] . '</td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? What does `var_dump($_POST['gejala']);` show?

Comment: This code gets data _from_ the database, it doesn't save anything _to_ the database (as per your description)

Comment: WARNING! Your code is susceptible to SQL-Injection.